# The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.15.0' provider is not registered on the local machine. (System.Data) When Trying to Import Excel 2013 file into SSMS 18

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssms

I am getting the error in SSMS 18 when trying to import an excel file to a database:

> The operation could not be completed.
>
> ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
>
> The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.15.0' provider is not registered on the local machine. (System.Data)

When googling around for solutions, everyone seemed to have conflicting versions (64 vs. 32) but everything I am using is 64-bit.

System details:

- Windows 10 x64-bit
- Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 18 (Standard Edition (64-bit))
- Microsoft Excel 2013 64-bit

[image]

Answer (score 12):

To check what 64-bit ACE provider is installed on the machine, just execute the following command in SSMS:

**T-SQL**

```
EXEC master.sys.sp_MSset_oledb_prop;
```

You can see its screen shot below.

Overall, there are 3 existing versions of ACE: 12.0, 15.0, and 16.0
You can change a misleading Excel version: dropdown to one of them, i.e to whatever version is installed.

If you need to install any of the ACE providers:

- Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 (Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0)
  https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255
- Microsoft Access 2013 Runtime (Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.15.0)
  https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=39358
- Microsoft Access Database Engine 2016 (Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.16.0)
  https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54920

[image]

**UPDATE**

To update ACE properties please issue the following commands:

```
USE [master] 
GO 
EXEC master.dbo.sp_MSset_oledb_prop N'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', N'AllowInProcess', 1 
GO 
EXEC master.dbo.sp_MSset_oledb_prop N'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', N'DynamicParameters', 1 
GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_MSset_oledb_prop N'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', N'DisallowAdHocAccess', 0
GO 
EXEC master.dbo.sp_MSset_oledb_prop N'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.16.0', N'AllowInProcess', 1 
GO 
EXEC master.dbo.sp_MSset_oledb_prop N'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.16.0', N'DynamicParameters', 1 
GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_MSset_oledb_prop N'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.16.0', N'DisallowAdHocAccess', 0
GO
```

Comment: I installed Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.16.0 but the value of "allow_in_process" is 0, how can I set this value to 1??

Comment: I  added it to the **UPDATE** section in that answer. Check it out.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue but I resolved it by installing 'Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable'
[Download the file using this link](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255)

Make sure you download the 32-bit version if you're running 32-bit version of Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio or 64-bit version if you're running 64-bit version of Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio

You can check which version of Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio you're running by
Step 1: Run the application
Step 2: Open up task manager and you'll see the version you're currently running
[Task manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oUhEX.png)

After all installation, Reboot your PC